# Norm of element from dual space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I am reading the following book:
[The Mathematical Tools for the Study of the Incompressible NS](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9781461459743)
And here is one of the propositions (Proposition II.2.1):

> Let $E$ be a normed vector space. Then $\forall x \in E$ and $\forall f \in E^{'}$ (dual space) one can have:
>
> $||x||_{E} = sup_{\substack{f\in E^{'}} \\ f \neq 0}\frac{|<f,x>|_{E^{'},E}}{||f||}=\mathrm{sup}_{\substack{||f||_{E^{'}}}\leq 1}|<f,x>|_{E^{'},E}$
>
> in which $<f,x>_{E,E^{'}} = f(x)$ is the dulaity bracket.

My question is the second equal sign. I think it should be $||f||_{E^{'}} \geq 1$?

Comment: No, the definition is OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is fine as it is written.  Note that the map

$$E\to\mathbb [0,\infty]\qquad x\mapsto\sup_{||f||\geq 1}|\langle f,x\rangle|$$
takes $0$ to $0$ , and every nonzero $x\in E$ to $\infty$.  Indeed, if $x\neq 0$, then by the Hahn-Banach theorem, there is some nonzero $f\in E'$ with $\|f\|=1$ and $f(x)=\|x\|$.  Then for all $M>1$, we have 
$$\sup_{||f||\geq 1}|\langle f,x\rangle|\geq\langle Mf,x\rangle=M\|x\|,$$
whence $\sup_{||f||\geq 1}|\langle f,x\rangle|=\infty$.

Comment: sorry if it is trivial: Let's say (I found this example online) $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}(3x^2-1)$ in $[-1,1]$. Then $||f||_2=\sqrt{2/5}<1$. And $|<f,x>|=|\frac{1}{2}(3x^2-1)|$. Then I think the first equal sign give me $1/\sqrt{2/5}$ and the second one just the number $1$. So we lower the upper bound. Sorry if it is stupid.

Comment: two things:  $[-1,1]$ is not a normed vector space, and $f$ is not linear.

Comment: and another thing:  I don't know how you used these equations, you have to take the supremum over all $f\in E'$ with the specified properties.

Comment: Thanks I got it now. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome, glad to help.  If you're satisfied with my answer, feel free to accept it, so that no one gets the wrong idea and tries to answer.

Comment: I have tried but it kept telling me that: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: @mko click on the green check mark, not the upvote button.